# How to customize AR.js camera?

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, ar.js

We have a simple group project in AR.js.
Goal is to add simple object created by us (like a chair) with hiro marker. Question is how is it possible to add side menu to choose over our items and print them on the scene. We already understand how to change object but can't add overlay in front of camera view.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to achieve this is by adding a HTML element before or after the scene, then position it absolutely with CSS and make sure its `z-index` is high enough to be shown. This will put the HTML element in front of the rendered `video` output.